# c# void return function error? what it is mean Public Main() method is required in a public class

Tags: c#

what is wrong with below c# ?
I got error says:"Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a public class
"

```
using System.Reflection;

public class Printing
{
    public void Fib()
    {
        Console.Write(9999);
        return;
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Printing printing = new Printing();
        printing.Fib();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a capital M on Main.

Answer (score 1):

C# case sensitive, you need to uppercase the M in `Main`, right now it's lowercase m as in `main`

```
public static void Main()
{
    Printing printing = new Printing();
    printing.Fib();
}
```